# Passing paragraph text to a JavaScript function

Tags: javascript

Im having trouble getting this text to speech JavaScript to speak a whole paragraph. It works fine with a text input box on a form but I want a button which will read out the paragraph of text.

Here's my code:

```html
<body>
  <h1>Web page heading</h1>
  <p id="speakit">Welcome to my web page</p>
  <button onclick="speak(words.value)">Say it</button>

  <script>
    function speak(words) {
      const speach = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance();

      // set the text to be spoken
      speach.text = words;

      // create an instance of the speech synthesis object
      const speechSynthesis = window.speechSynthesis;

      // start speaking
      speechSynthesis.speak(speach);
    }
  </script>
</body>
```

When I click the button, nothing happens.

Comment: *"When I click the button, nothing happens."* - An error happens.  Now is the time to start using your browser's development tools, observing the error message on the console.  Specifically, when you call `speak(words.value)`, what do you expect `words` (and `words.value`) to be and why?

Comment: You're calling the function `speak(words.value)` but where is `words` defined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be done this way using `getElementById(id).textContent` and it should be `speech` not `speach`

```html
<body>
  <h1>Web page heading</h1>
  <p id="speakit">Welcome to my web page</p>
  <button onclick="speak()">Say it</button>

  <script>
    function speak() {
      const speech = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance();
      const text = document.getElementById("speakit").textContent;

      // Set the text to be spoken
      speech.text = text;

      // Create an instance of the speech synthesis object
      const speechSynthesis = window.speechSynthesis;

      // Start speaking
      speechSynthesis.speak(speech);
    }
  </script>
</body>
```

Comment: Perfect! Works great. I did try getElement by ID but not with textContent. Thanks!

Comment: @AlanJarvis Glad that your issue is resolved. Please accept the answer if that works for you